# app supports all devices

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I've built a app for iOS 6 that is designed for landscape mode and it works just fine but not on ios 7. In ios 7, orientation problem occurs and i solved too using 3.9 AIR SDK instead of 3.2 SDK.

I tried this link but doesn't work for me,
[AS3 - iOS force landscape mode only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559265/as3-ios-force-landscape-mode-only)

My Question: 
I built an app only for ipad but i want to use my app in All Android Tablet, Iphones, Ipods, 
& All Small Screen Devices to be able to Landscape direction.  Is this possible in adobe flash or actionscript 3.0.

Comment: What orientation problem occurs? What have you tried and how did you fail? We need more info here.

Comment: i tried like this http://mds.scaleviz.com/as3/supporting-multiple-screen-sizes-with-as3/ but doesn't work for me.