# Can't get AIR app to display in landscape mode in iOS (AS3)

Tags: ios, iphone, actionscript-3, air

This issue is happening in iOS ONLY, all android and pc versions of the app display in landscape mode fine with no issues

I am trying to get the app to display in landscape mode in iOS OR at the very least be able to orient to landscape mode when the iphone/ipad is tilted to landscape position

However no matter what I try the app will always open in portrait mode
The dimensions are 480x320 and I have tried setting the aspectratio in publish options to landscape, I have even tried

stage.setAspectRatio(StageAspectRatio.LANDSCAPE);

I have also tried adding "aspectRatio> landscape /aspectRatio>" to the XML file

I have been looking for DAYS for a fix on this issue and nothing works
Please some one help!

Comment: Try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559265/as3-ios-force-landscape-mode-only

Comment: But does manually setOrientation work on iOS? If so, a possible (ugly) workaround would be to track the Gyro for positioning. I had some trouble in the past with stageOrienation as well and went over to just rely on the Gyro for Orientations. So check if setting the Orientation manually does work for you first.

Comment: funny because I set the app to portrait and now it publishes as landscape. I guess some one at adobe made a big mistake

Answer (score 0):

How are you publishing your app (i.e. FlashCC, FlashBuilder etc) and are you using the latest AIR SDK?

Publishing landscape only iOS apps is definitely possible with AIR so I suspect it's going to be an issue with how your settings currently are.

If you're targeting iPads perhaps try including a landscape default image. 
Default-Landscape.png, Default-LandscapeRight.png etc.